# Ruby String concatenation and ternary don't play nice?

Tags: ruby, concatenation

On the following code, the third line errors with:
TypeError: can't convert false into String

```
line = "some default text"
line << " some more text" unless more.empty?
line << (even_more.empty?) ? " done." : " and even more text"
```

What is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Those parens are necessary because `<<` has higher precedence than `?` ([precedence table](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.4)). Solution:

```
line << (even_more.empty? ? " done." : " and even more text")
```

As a side note, notice that you can take a functional approach when building arrays:

```
line = [
  "some default text",
  ("some more text" unless more.empty?),
  even_more.empty? ? "done." : "and even more text",
].compact.join(" ")
```

Comment: You could add that the issue is cause by the fact the << operator has a higher precedence than the ternary ?: operator... Hence the need for brackets.

Comment: parentheses are your friends, not the enemy :)